# Prevent tabs dancing for all actions page

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, localization

There's a tab "dancing" (tab and text on the same row or not) on All Actions page of User Profile for ruSO and rusSE due to long enough words used in translations:

> [image: tab dancing]

Could we please somehow fix this behavior without using other shorter translations?

BTW it's not an issue on mobile (portrait mode) at least, since text always occupies its own row:

> [image: mobile portrait ok]